Douglas Rachford operator
I am interested in applying the Douglas Rachford algorithm to the problem $\min_x \{h(x) + g(x)\}$. The Douglas Rachford operator is defined as
\begin{equation*}
F_{DR}(w) = \dfrac{1}{2}(w + R_h(R_g(w))),
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
R_h(x) = 2\text{prox}_h(x) - x.
\end{equation*}
Let $\mathcal{F}_{F_{DR}}$ denote the set of fixed points of $F_{DR}$. Let $\overline{X}:=\text{argmin}_x\{h(x) + g(x)\}$. I read that $\overline{X} = \{\text{prox}_h(\overline{w}): \overline{w} \in \mathcal{F}_{F_{DR}}\}$, but I do not see why this is true. Would be very grateful if someone could shed some light on this, thanks!
